# Running a Jupyter notebook from another notebook

Tags: python, return, jupyter-notebook

I wonder if it is possible to run a *.ipynb file from another *.ipynb file and get a returned value.
I know that we can run like this:

```
%run ./called_notebook.ipynb
```

the called_notebook contains:

```
def foo():
    print(1)
    return 2
foo()
```

But it only prints "1" without giving me the opportunity to handle the returned value. Is it even possible ? Does the following kind of code even exist :

```
a = %run ./called_notebook.ipynb
```

?

Thanks !

Comment: I tried this, but the command appends '.py' to the end of the file. I'm using Jupyter Lab 3.2.4

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'd suggest running the `foo` function from the new notebook. In other words:

```
%run ./called_notebook.ipynb
foo()
```

In my opinion, this is best practices for using the `%run` magic command. Store your high level APIs in a separate notebook (such as `foo`), but keep your function calls visible in the master notebook.

Comment: Note, that it can even be inside an `if` statement, e.g.: `if need_to_run(): %run ...`

Comment: If that notebook defines some huge object in a global scope will that object be reinstantiated each time you use the run command?

Comment: sweet! One question/remark... called_notebook is run, and all print/display/etc. commands displayed, but any result at the end of a cell that would normaly be displayed, will not be so.

Comment: how to run all cells of a notebook from a different notebook

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for a long time. Quick question: and how to stop the other script from within this one?

Answer (score 1):

Matt's Answer works. However I wanted to run from calling_notebook.ipynb the other called_notebook.ipynb and transfer data frame from called_notebook to calling_notebook WITHOUT displaying any of the output.

I tried many options all did not work (tags etc). However this below worked (suppressed all output in called_notebook.ipynb).

```
    # to suppress output of the cell
    %%capture        
    %run -n ./called_notebook.ipynb  
    df = DFF()       # function in called_notebook that returns a dataframe after doing all work
    df.info()
```

Comment: I want to achieve the following. How to do that? 1. Create an .ipynb (lets say helper_functions.ipynb) with the following functions i). read several input files ii). transform the data iii). merge the files iv). log the size of original datasets and visualize final merged dataset as a data frame  2. Create another .ipynb (lets say main.ipynb) that calls the helper functions i) to iv). How to achieve this? And if there are errors in the helper_functions.ipynb how to capture them?

Comment: Srikrishna, let us assume that you have a wrangling notebook by the name called_notebook.ipynb the commands above (which must be included in your calling_notebook.ipynb will run that notebook then call a function inside that notebook called DFF(); Now inside your called_notebook.ipynb you will have the following functions defined def DFF():
    return dff

Comment: Note the DFF() function must appear at the bottom of your notebook so that all above cells which will execute your i) to iv) will run first. These cells can include all that you want visualization logs etc. All this happens inside the called_notebook.ipynb which at the end will generate the dff (dataframe you need in your calling_notebook.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the magic tag "%store <variable?" and "%store -r "? It is a way to store data in the iPython storing space, and you may share variables in runtime whether the notebooks are run in the same iPython instance.